# Dynamically Create and Use Django Database Connections for Each School Without Server Restart

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django application where schools can register, and each school has its own database. However, I am facing an issue: after creating a new database for a school, the Django server needs to be restarted for the new database to be recognized.

I want to dynamically create database connections for each school without having to restart the Django server. I've tried various approaches, including creating dynamic connections using django.db.connections, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Is there a solution or recommended approach to allow Django to dynamically create and use database connections for each new school without requiring a server restart?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

```
ConnectionDoesNotExist at /inscription/ecole/

The connection 'school_db_belle_rose' doesn't exist.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/inscription/ecole/
Django Version:     5.0
Exception Type:     ConnectionDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

The connection 'school_db_belle_rose' doesn't exist.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Ppang\Desktop\project_procode\ConnectEdu\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py, line 61, in __getitem__
Raised during:  comptes_ecole.views.InscriptionEcole
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Ppang\Desktop\project_procode\ConnectEdu\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.11.0
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Ppang\\Desktop\\project_procode\\ConnectEdu\\back-end',
 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Ppang\\Desktop\\project_procode\\ConnectEdu\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Ppang\\Desktop\\project_procode\\ConnectEdu\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 08 Jan 2024 02:22:52 +0000
```

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) some short test code which successfully connects to one school but fails to properly connect to second school.

Comment: Can you share how we connect with the database?
I think when you start the service, it will create a new connection, please try that when a new database created

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.